# SELECT COUNT with LIKE gives strange result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL-database with a table that has a mediumtext column. When trying to count the number of rows that has a specific word within that column, I get some strange result.

When I do this;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS antal FROM ot_pages where otp_ocr_raw LIKE '%vass%'
```

I get a count of around 860.
If I instead do a simple SELECT with the same question, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ot_pages where otp_ocr_raw LIKE '%vass%'
```

I get a recordset with 70 rows back. Why is that? What would a correct SELECT COUNT-query look like to get a count of just 70?

Comment: Presumably because the tool that you are using is limiting the result to 70 rows -- or you are querying different databases.

Comment: I wish the solution would be that simple, but no. It's definitely the same database. And if I do a more generic search I get both a higher count, as well as more rows. And vice versa; a more narrow query gives a smaller count and fewer records back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. The query contained letters like ÅÄÖ.
When I preformed a ordinary SELECT-query, those letters where correctly interpreted. But when doing a SELECT COUNT() those letters seems to have been interpreted by MySQL as AAO instead, hence giving a higher count than actual rows in the recordset.

The solution was to use utf8mb4 as charset, both in the script and the actual column. Now everything seems to work.